# Graph theory(Trees)

Tags: graph-theory

There are 100 towns in a country and some of them are connected by airlines. It is known that one can reach every town from any other (perhaps with several intermediate stops). Prove that you can fly around the country and visit all the. towns making no more than a) 198 flights; b) 196 flights

I have been trying this question for a some days. Following  is a "relevant" thought/idea I could get :

1)I considered some random graphs satisfying the details provided . First I considered a graph with a vertex v that is connected to all other vertices and none of the other vertices are connected to each other and so the degree of vertex is 99 and of others is 1. Secondly I considered a path but I found that it was a quite stupid idea.

Any help would be highly appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the spanning tree of this connected graph. It has $100-1=99$ edges. It is clear that we can visit all its vertices passing each edge no more then $2$ times, hence the path with $198$ edges.

Now if we start from a hanging vertex which any (big enough) tree has, we don’t have to go back to that vertex anymore, hence the path with $197$ edges. Also such a path can always be made in such a way that it ends in a hanging vertex. We don’t have to go back there either, hence the path with $196$ edges.

It is probably best to formalize this reasoning by use of the induction method. Let $n$ be a number of vertices in a tree. Prove that there is a path with $2n-4$ edges visiting all the vertices.

If $n=3$ then it’s clear that there is a path of length $2n-4=2$. Suppose we have proven the statement for $n-1$. Now we have a tree with $n$ edges. It has a hanging vertex. Delete it and its edge. The rest is a tree and there is a path with $2(n-1)-4=2n-6$ edges. Now we just return the deleted vertex and its edge. It adds $2$ edges to the path. So we need $2n-4$ edges and we’re done.

Comment: Thanks Aig for your support . It  really helped me .